# Visual Studio Usings Plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins

I find the usings remove and sort ability to be highly useful, but does anyone know of a tool that will scan my code looking for unrecognized types, look through available namespaces, and offer me possible listings to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio will do that with assemblies that your project has references to.  Use a type whose namespace isn't already included, but is available via the referenced assemblies.  If you mouseover it, you'll get a little popup in the bottom, left corner of the symbol.  That will let you automatically pull in the appropriate using.

I use this all the time with the `CLSCompliantAttribute` in `AssemblyInfo.cs` b/c `System` isn't available there by default.  I also find myself pulling in `System.Diagnostics` this way pretty frequently when I find I need to add a trace to a bit of code.

Answer (score 2):

You do know about the shortcut key: Shft+Alt+F10 when the cursor is on the unrecognized type? Or if you are a mouse user I believe there is a dropdown...